# WEMO switch and Sodium lighting

Tags: switches, remote-control, lighting

Why can't the WEMO switch from Belkin be used with sodium discharge lights?

I am investigating the purchase of a switch to remote control some driveway lights which I believe are sodium discharge lights (long time to turn on; amber color).

The Belkin WEMO light switch has ratings for LED, incandescent and halogen lights.  When I contacted customer support, I was told they could NOT control sodium lights, but he did not know why.

Can anyone here enlighten me?

Thanks.

Comment: Sodium lights require an inductive ballast to get them to strike, I suspect the switch isn't designed for their demands.

Comment: @Finbarr Thanks.  I guess they probably still use a magnetic ballast. I'll have to research the kind of demands that are inherent in that sort of starter.

Comment: something with a relay should work.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks.  I did find this [Web Relay](https://www.controlbyweb.com/webrelay/). But it's more expensive and more difficult to set up than the WEMO, so I was wondering about the characteristics of the Sodium lamps that made using Belkin's WEMO switch not feasible.

Comment: well, you can use the wemo and a wall wort to power a "cheap" 12v relay that can switch the bigger load (if you're handy with wiring). the wemo turns on the wall wart, the 12v DC turns on the relay, which connects the mains. Assuming the wemo plays nice with your system, this is an easier integration than messing with multiple smart device vendors / ecosystems.

Comment: @dandavis That's not a bad idea, assuming the WEMO has no problem with a wall wart.